# Convention badge deluge of meta questions for 2015 moderator election?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-election

Is there usually a big spike in the incoming Meta questions during a moderator election?  People who wish to become moderator will notice they need the convention badge which requires 10 questions on Meta with a score at least two.

This would seem to cause the phenomenon of individuals asking questions with the sole purpose of getting upvotes on Meta without any substance.

I think the site runs near perfectly, so any question I could possibly have is already addressed on Meta.  But one thing we haven't yet discussed is: "Why 10 questions and why 2 upvotes?"

Wasn't it at least 2 questions of at least 10 points upvoted last year?  And is there a way I can speed up my seven remaining required posts without clogging up the tubes with already-asked questions since two of my other submissions are upvoted really high?

Comment: You are missing something important. It is 10 posts (Q+A), not asking 10 questions

Comment: Perhaps.  The more notable pattern you'll see emerge is that the candidates start participating in meta Q+A and create long posts to assert all is well.  To disappear again when the election is over :)  Ah, looks like Ed is back.

Comment: Turns out, the [answers tab of a meta profile sorted by newest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4320665/ryanyuyu?tab=answers&sort=newest) easily exposes people rushing to get in meta exposure during election time.

Comment: In asking this, it's quite likely that someone on here somewhere is now going to be watching your posts to see if that's what _you_ do. (Not saying you will or would, just a word of warning.) If you do get the badge before nomination ends and nominate yourself, I would be prepared for someone to bring this post up in the comments of your nomination.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm hoping that was more of a friendly greeting than a subtle dig. :) But your point is definitely a fair one.

Comment: The process by which overly aggressive power-grabbing behavior by individuals is checked is probably the most important thing.  Apparently the system here isn't like the one in the real world, where money equals power, and you can exchange one for the other.

Comment: Well... my opinion on that is negotiable! (As read on [english.se]: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/284729)

Comment: Interestingly enough (sadly enough for me?) that requirement of 10 questions with +2 votes doesn't seem to have given me my convention badge. Maybe I can buy one with my spare meta-unicoins...

Comment: Maybe the rule should be "must have the convention badge (and the other pre-requisite badges) when the election is announced" so that it is too late to game the system for the current election once it is announced?

Answer (score 16):

Any time there's a large event going on, you're going to see a deluge of questions on Meta about it - that's just natural. Not everyone will be asking for the same reason, but it's just one of those things that draws extra attention to Meta while it's ongoing.

That said, that's not really a problem. If they're asking *good* questions that are getting upvotes, then it's a good thing we directed them over here because they're participating in our community in a way they haven't done much before, and it's resulting in positive discussion among the rest of the community. The Meta community certainly isn't reluctant to close down questions which don't fit in well, *or* point out that you might be doing it just to reach some thresholds.

Even if they're only doing it to get that badge so they can participate in the election, it's probably not going to help them all that much - because it's obvious. There are many users here who are very particular about the moderators they're willing to vote for, and if you've never participated much in Meta before the election popped up, **they're going to point it out**. It's easy to see that all of their activity is recent, and you're guaranteed to get slammed with a comment somewhere along the lines of "Are you really interested in helping or are you just doing things in hopes to get elected?"

What's most important is that you don't just give up if you don't win the election. Meta participation is a factor for a reason, and if you want to improve your chances for any future elections, even if you don't end up reaching the requirements this time, *just keep participating*. Keep an eye out for things that interest you or anything you could help out with. It goes a long way.

Comment: The third paragraph, so much. Tryhards always make it so obvious in their tryharding. It's the *definition* of "tryhard" (i.e. [this](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=try-hard&defid=2639394), and not the word used by a sore loser to describe whomever they lost to).

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR** I don't think this is a problem.

It seems like there is always a surge of activity on Meta during elections, yes. Personally, I have never noticed any problems with would-be moderator candidates posting excessive numbers of (bad) questions or answers. Most serious mod candidates already have the Convention badge, anyway, and the nomination period is actually a pretty short window in which to write 10 good posts that aren't duplicates of existing posts.

> This would seem to cause the phenomenon of individuals asking questions with the soul purpose of getting up votes on meta without any substance.

I haven't seen this happening. Keep in mind that Meta votes don't mean the same thing as main site votes. If the post in question isn't any good ("without any substance"), it will get voted into the sub-basement. Also keep in mind that it's easy to check who's doing this on [their profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2057919/ed-cottrell?tab=answers&sort=newest), as several other people have pointed out.

> I think the site runs near perfectly, so any question I could possibly have is already addressed on meta. But one thing we haven't yet discussed is: "Why 10 questions and why 2 upvotes?"
>
> Wasn't it at least 2 questions of at least 10 points upvoted last year?

As far as I know, the Convention badge has always been 10 posts with a score of 2, never 2 posts with a score of 10. It's much harder to write 10 posts that are considered good than to write 2 posts that happen to hit a nerve. The criteria help show that anyone holding that badge really has contributed, on many occasions, to the Meta site.

As for your final question:

> And is there a way I can speed up my seven remaining required posts without clogging up the tubes with already-asked questions since two of my other submissions are upvoted really high?

Yes! Write seven more good posts. :) Seriously, if you have a good question or good answer to a question, please share. If not, well... please don't.

Comment: +1 for the last line ... seriously, sums it up. Good posts are good, if they're not good, don't post :P.